# Replacing ORM schema without dropping the entire data

Tags: java, database, jpa, openjpa

I'm using OpenJPA as a JPA provider.
Is there a way in which I can recreate the database tables (When an entity changes) without dropping the entire data?
When an entity changes, I drop and create every table in the store, and obviously lose the data within. Is there a tool or product to keep the data somehow?

Thanks, 
Udi

Comment: why would you recreate the tables?  Do you mean an entity as in a persistent object?  And that you want to maybe add/remove/modify fields of an entity and it's database table?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the `refresh` action of the [SchemaTool](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.2/apache-openjpa-1.0.2/docs/manual/ref_guide_schema_schematool.html) is what you're looking for and my understanding is that you use it like this in the `persistence.xml`:

```
<property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" 
          value="buildSchema(SchemaAction=refresh,ForeignKeys=true)" />
```